# Load first category on landing page by default

Tags: php, mysql

the question is simple but I and new and don't know how to do this.

So, I have categories in my database which I already show on the page, like this

```
<?php
     foreach ($categories as $cat) {
         if ($cat == false)
               continue;
?>
     <li>
          <a href="topic?tag=<?php echo $cat['word']?>"><?php echo $cat['word']?></a>
     </li>
<?php }?>
```

And the JS with which I highlighting the selected category

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var active = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
         if (document.links[i].href === document.URL) {
              active = i;
         }
    }
    document.links[active].className = 'active';    
})
```

Everything works fine but when I try to open the page with all categories I want to select first category by default and load items only from that category.

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Note: categories are populated dynamically in database and I don't know what name of category will be first.

Comment: You can get first category like this `$categories[0]`

Comment: Give the li a category css class, then do `$('li.category:first-child').addClass('active');`

Comment: Where I should put this? In my current JS inside the `if`? And how to load the items for this category also.

Comment: You want to load item list of first category?

Comment: bottom line when I open the page `topic.php` it must load `topic.php?tag=<firstcategory>` this `tag=...` will load items

Comment: yes, by default

Comment: @delboy1978uk, I've tried it and I see in source that class `active` is added to the button but can't change the color of it. `.category ul li { color: #fff; }` doesn't work

Comment: Yes, because you want a rule for `.category ul li.active` as well now  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the li a category css class, then do this:

```
$('li.category:first-child').addClass('active');
```

Then set a CSS class rule for `.active`:

```
li.category.active {
    color: green; // or whatever
}
```

Comment: Why if I put `class="category"` on `a href=""` doesn't select only first child but all of them

Comment: because they ALL have class category. li.category.active only selects li's with both category and active classes

Comment: Finally got it to work. Is there a way after click on other category name (once the page is loaded and first item is "active") to change the active state because now I have 2 active..

Comment: something like this `$('li.category').click(function(){$('li.category').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active')});`

Comment: Thanks but they are still both active. The clicked one and the `:first` item

Comment: dont remove class from the first child. remove from all of them! look at the code i wrote you!

Comment: Еven then the result is same. I can't understand what is wrong here. It must be with some kind of condition if is not first element - remove from first and add to whatever is clicked

Comment: You just forgot to add jQuery to your fiddle! I also removed the active class from your HTML markup since you add the class in your JS http://jsfiddle.net/t9gf2bjd/27/

Answer (score 0):

Use ***trigger*** of jquery.

1. First give unique id to anchor tag

like

```
<a id="cat_<?php echo $cat['word']?>" href="topic?tag=<?php echo $cat['word']?>"> 
    <?php echo $cat['word']?>
</a>
```

2. Then trigger click event on the first link using id

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#cat_<?php $categories[0]['word'];?>')[0].click();        
   });
   ```

Hope this work!

Comment: Last question. How can I limit the number of categories which are show to 10? If they are 15 I want to show 10, first one to be loaded by default.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't seems to trigger the `click` event

Comment: @Ivanov I changed code for click.For limit get limited categories(ie 10) from database OR use counter in foreach

Comment: Click event is working now but doesn't change the category name color. It should be change it since is active now

Comment: Then you need to done this manually by adding class  $'#cat_<?php $categories[0]['word'];?>').addClass('active');  after click event as answered by @delboy1978uk

Comment: It doesn't add any class to the active link

Comment: Actually it is adds the class but when I click on it. Not when the page load and click even is done. I must actually click on the link

Comment: sorry but I've got error with this code. In my browser console I see `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined`